# What is the meaning of the Name "Devuan" (the debian forked distribution)

Tags: debian, devuan

What is the meaning of the name "Devuan"?
(It is the "systemd"-less **distribution forked from debian**!)
The same way I wanted to know what debian means (and I was disappointed after I found out ^^) I would like to know what "Devuan" means.
Is it (like the naming-convention of their releases) a **planet**? (I didn't found that).
 Sound like a **dragon**, but I don't think so. 

Or does it have something to do with **deviant**?

Comment: Debian is a portmonteau of "Deborah loves Ian", Ian is the inventor of Debian. I do not know the answer, but there are a lot of play on words in Linux, my guess it that maybe some Dev... loves ...uan.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devuan

Comment: The development group is named VUA (Veteran Unix Adminis) which are the middle letters of the name. But it might be a retronym from the name.

Comment: @Barmar the VUA name was used (just) before Devuan, when the fork was still just http://debianfork.org (see [this message](https://lists.dyne.org/lurker/message/20141107.164901.8e7c394d.en.html)). A few days later [Devuan was announced](https://lists.dyne.org/lurker/message/20141127.212941.f55acc3a.en.html), but the name wasn’t explained in the announcement.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2nuhjb/one_of_the_individuals_behind_the_debian_fork/ says "First of all, who are the "Veteran Unix Admins", or VUAs. VUAs are a group of individuals associated with a private forum, created around 3 years ago by a group of "old" sysadmins. These were all friends, mostly from the Milan area.

The name comes from: http://www.infoworld.com/article/2623488/unix/nine-traits-of-the-veteran-unix-admin.html We had an internal definition, by which a VUA is someone who identifies in at least 5 (or better, 6) of the listed points."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, from the comment and further search, it seems that it's
Debian forked by some people who call themselves **V**eteran **U**nix **A**dministrators *(see the comment to the question)*

Debian + VUA = deVUAn

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2nuhjb/one_of_the_individuals_behind_the_debian_fork/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devuan

Comment: This is confirmed by the [Devuan team page](https://devuan.org/os/team/): “promoted by a large group of senior anonymous IT professionals that is known by the name of ***Veteran UNIX Admins***, hence the ***VUA*** in the name.”

Comment: thanks @StephenKitt - I searched their site before asking - maybe they added that information now?! (or I did not looked correctly)

Comment: The page hasn’t changed recently (see the [web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20170505142202/https://devuan.org/os/team/)) but I hadn’t noticed it either ;-). I just came across it while reading a thread on LWN and thought of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the name comes from a typo? "v" is one character to the left of "b" and "u" is one character to the left of "i" on a QWERTY keyboard.  I could see someone typing it by accident once and then deciding it's a good name.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but it means both hands were shifted to the left, since "i" is on the right side and "b" and "v" are on the left. Yet he didn't miss any of the other characters. But maybe he was hunting and pecking on a mobile device's keyboard, not touch typing.